# Run through more than 2 Statements

Tags: php, echo

I have struggled with this code below to get no more than two variables to filter through the statement sections, but what wish to achieve is running as many as variables needed and filter through them. see code below

**Setup Variable**

```
    <?php 
      $customergroup = $product['product_id'] ;
    ?>
```

**Run Through The Code**

```
    <?php 

      if ($customergroup == "1" || $customergroup == "2") 
      { 
      ?>
         first content if variable is/equals 1

    <?php } else { ?>

         Second content if variable is/equals 2
    <?php } ?>
```

I have tried the code below in the filter and added the "else" in each break

```
($customergroup == "1" || $customergroup == "2" || $customergroup == "3" || $customergroup == "4")
```

But could not get it to echo content based on variable also have had to add a space in the =="2 " before to get the "2" section to echo the content even though the variable echos with no space

Any help appreciated

cheers

Comment: I still don't understand what is you problem

Comment: i can only echo the content of the first two if statements, but i wish to run through as many if statements as possible but work with 4 for now

Comment: Your code does output something: http://codepad.org/emRkTmsg But I think you're confused as far as what happens in an `if` block. One condition per value, e.g., `1 ... 2`, is what you seem to want. Or a `switch` or some other construct.

Comment: For instance, this is what you seem to be describing: http://codepad.org/hybsElRC

Comment: yes but how can i use <?php echo $foo ?> in the content without resorting to '.$foo.'

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
switch($customergroup){
    case 1:
        ?>first content if variable is/equals 1<?php
        break;
    case 2:
        ?>Second content if variable is/equals 2<?php
        break;
    case 3:
        ?>and so on - just keep adding cases<?php
        break;
}
?>
```

**EDIT:** Modified to use statement blocks

Comment: yes but i wish to have the echoed content as statements using <?php echo ?> within the content as abit of code would be in these sections and having to use echo ''; the code would become tedious

Comment: see here http://codepad.org/f4TYo0C2 something like this but yeah like what you have posted